# Why my TextFormField value doesn't change here?

Tags: flutter, dart

Well it's probably a very simple question but I'm starting and I'm not able to find too much documentation about flutter...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AutoChangeField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AutoChangeFieldState createState() => _AutoChangeFieldState();
}

class _AutoChangeFieldState extends State<AutoChangeField> {

  Color _color = Colors.black;
  String _newValue = 'write something';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      initialValue: _newValue,
      cursorColor: _color,
      onChanged: (val){
        setState(() {
          _newValue = "It changed!";
          _color = Colors.red;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Just the cursorColor swaps to red properly when you write something at the TextFormField, but the value of it does not. Value keeps being "write something + (what u writed)" instead of "It changed!". :(

Thanks you so much.

Comment: what you try to achieve?

Comment: In this nothing. It's just an example. I wanna complete a textformfield in base to another textformfield value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `TextEditingController` and set the initialValue of the `TextEditingController` to "Write something"

Like this

```dart
class AutoChangeField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AutoChangeFieldState createState() => _AutoChangeFieldState();
}

class _AutoChangeFieldState extends State<AutoChangeField> {

  Color _color = Colors.black;
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(text: "Write something");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      cursorColor: _color,
      onChanged: (val){
        print(val);
        controller.text = "It changed!";
        setState(() {
          _color = Colors.red;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** You cannot use the controller and initialValue at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 'controller' proeprty.

Define a controller like below :

```
TextEditingController myController = new TextEditingController();
```

Assign it to the TextFormField as :

```
TextFormField(
      controller: myController,
```

Now, assign a new value as :

```
myController.text = "its changed";
```

Comment: Gash ty, so easy it was... so noob I am yet ^^